# Copy text from Αce editor to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I am trying to copy the text from inside an Ace Editor box into my local clipboard, using the pure JS method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1650200). However, when I click my copy button, it will throw me an error:

> "TypeError: copyTextarea.select is not a function"

and the text will not copy to my clipboard. Is there a way to do this somehow (either pure JS or jQuery)? My code is as follows (simplified but should be enough):

```js
$('#clipboard').on('click', function() {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('#result-box');
  copyTextarea.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```html
<button id="clipboard">Copy</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-box" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #DDD;">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; 
  &lt;html&gt; 
  &lt;/html&gt;</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit("result-box");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
  editor.setReadOnly(true);
  editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
  editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
</script>
```

**P.S.**: There is another error thrown about some worker and whatnot concerning Ace, if anyone knows how to fix that, too, comment below. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to have a look at https://apidoc.c9.io/c9v3/#!/api/clipboard

Comment: @GibboK, nope, you can use that command without problems as long as the textarea is visible http://jsfiddle.net/ourcodeworld/wrL0j3xu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select method should be available in the **textarea** as a native method, and you're using it in a **div** (which is what ace requires to work).

Retrieve the value from the editor, set that value to a **textarea** and then copy the content using your method.

You can retrieve the text of Ace using getValue :

```
<button id="clipboard">Copy</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-box" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #DDD;">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; 
  &lt;html&gt; 
  &lt;/html&gt;</div>
<textarea id="clipboard-content"></textarea>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
      var editor = ace.edit("result-box");
      editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
      editor.setReadOnly(true);
      editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
      editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);

      $('#clipboard').on('click', function() {
          var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('#clipboard-content');
          copyTextarea.value = editor.getValue();
          copyTextarea.select();
          document.execCommand('copy');
          // Reset textarea
          copyTextarea.value = "";
      });
</script>
```

However note that the method that you're using to copy the text, will not work if you hide the textarea.

I recommend you to use a plugin instead, [read the following article to see possible solutions](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/143/how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-easily) with pure javascript and fallbacks with flash (using js).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well enough for me. Adding the `textarea` dynamically and removing after copying did the trick without making the page look any different from before.

Answer (score 7):

call `focus` and `selectAll` on the editor, it works on most of modern browsers

```js
$('#clipboard').on('click', function() {
  var sel = editor.selection.toJSON(); // save selection
  editor.selectAll();
  editor.focus();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  editor.selection.fromJSON(sel); // restore selection
});
```

```html
<button id="clipboard">Copy</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-box" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #DDD;">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; 
  &lt;html&gt; 
  &lt;/html&gt;</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit("result-box");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
  editor.setReadOnly(true);
  editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
  editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but how would I go about deselecting everything afterwards? I want it to look seamless and not show any of the inner workings to the user (I know this sounds a bit lame, but it is what I was asked to do).

Comment: updated the answer to restore the selection after the copy